# What are the correct singular and plural ways to list pita bread?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number, vocabulary

What are the correct singular and plural ways to list pita bread?

Possibilities I can think of:

- one pita, two pitas
- one pita bread, two pita breads
- one piece of pita bread, two pieces of pita bread

Are those all correct and equivalent? Are there other correct ways?

Comment: Figuring out what ARE the correct singular and plural ways to list pita bread is a real P.I.T.A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pita has been counted as loaves [Merriam-Webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loaf) in English, as most breads have.

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=loaf%20of%20pita&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cloaf%20of%20pita%3B%2Cc0) suggests "loaf of pita" is a healthy term, also "loaves of pita" [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=loaf%20of%20pita&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cloaf%20of%20pita%3B%2Cc0), both terms having spiked in usage 30 years ago according the the Google count.

> one loaf of pita, two loaves of pita

are correct forms.
Pita pocket is also used [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pita%20pocket&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cpita%20pocket%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpita%20pocket%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPita%20Pocket%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPita%20pocket%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPITA%20POCKET%3B%2Cc0)

> one pita, two pitas

may be understood in context, but maybe not out of context

> one pita bread, two pita breads

Generally, *bread* is not a countable noun [English Grammar](https://www.englishgrammar.org/singular-plural-nouns/). Normally *breads* is used only when referring to different types of bread. One pita  (or
 two pita) breads is incorrect in referring  to loaves or pockets. .

> one piece of pita bread, two pieces of pita bread

*Pieces* might be used, but the listener or reader will not know if *piece* refers to a whole loaf or pocket, or part of a loaf or pocket.

It would be best to use:

> one loaf of pita, two loaves of pita

or

> one pita pocket, two pita pockets

Comment: How many pita pockets did pita piper pick?

Comment: @fixer1234            πέντε  πίττα

Comment: "*Pita has been counted as loaves Merriam-Webster,com in English,*" I see no mention of *pita* in the linked page. IMHO, what makes pita so special is that it's **not** shaped like a loaf.

Comment: @michael.hor257k         "a shaped or molded mass of bread", Merriam-Webster did not define a special shape for the mass., I do understand that many people think of "loaf" as a particular shape. I was defining loaves as it applies to bread, which "pita" is.. I am going to think on the wording. Thanks.

Comment: @J.Taylor That would be πέντε πίτες. Which goes to show that the Greeks consider them countable, by the way, giving _two pitas_ a sense of authenticity.

Comment: @oerkelens.... thanks for the correction.......I cannot, in English, count anything called "pita"... I am still asking around  and thinking on it

Comment: If the market accepts "pita" as a "flatbread pocket"  , then I will accept it too....much like "fajita: is in the market a type of sandwich, and not a cut of meat.

Comment: Very interesting answer. I didn't even think of a "loaf of pita" and I think this is the first I've ever heard that. I had heard of pita pockets, but pita can also be used not to hold anything (as a pizza crust is used, for example), and since pita pocket would seem to imply putting something inside it, I'd only think to use pita pocket if/when that were the case. i.e. I'm thinking of using it in recipes where it's not used as a pocket.

Comment: @ Dronz.....the related term, "pizza" is countable as it can represent a unit.. There may be people who speak of one or two pitas in English, but I would not. As far as I understand the world, "pita" is a type of bread (counted as loaves, or, "pockets")  and not a unit itself.  If a "pita" crust is used for "pizza", I would think the correct term would be "pita crust pizza".  Or, invent the word "PITZA"..